# How to skip a testNG class based on element visibility and switch to another class

Tags: selenium, testng, ui-automation

I am using testNG for my selenium suite. There is a class having 35 test cases. But these test cases will execute only if a particular element is visible. If that element is not visible, the compiler goes through all the test cases. Is there any way that I could check that element visibility condition in an @BeforeClass annotation only. If an element is not visible, it should come out from that class and switch to the next one? It will save my time to go through all the test cases?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve it use `@Test` annotation on class level and `@BeforeTest` to check element visibility so it will skip all test cases of class if it will not satisfy condition in `@BeforeTest`. See below code (it's tested and working).

```
@Test
public class SkipAllTestCases {

    boolean elementNotVisible=true;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {

        if (elementNotVisible) {

            throw new SkipException("skipping test cases...");
        }

    }

    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("Test1");

    }


    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("Test2");

    }


    public void test3() {
        System.out.println("Test3");

    }

}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi Muzzamil, it is still coming to test1, test2 and test3. If the condition in beforeTest is not being passed, it should not come to tests. I used beforeClass as well but no luck.

Comment: It will skip test cases if condition will be true. If visibility of element will be true then it will skip the test cases. Just copy and paste the code in my answer and try.

Comment: Please let me know if you are still facing problem. I have tested it so its working for me and full filing your requirement. I think its the problem of condition. If condition will be true then it will only skip test cases belong to the test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **dependsOnMethods** of TestNG Test annotation.

```
@Test
public void elementVisibleTest(){
  //Fail or skip here
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = {"elementVisibleTest"})
public void myOtherTest(){
  //Do something
}
...
```

That means if **elementVisibleTest** fails or gets skipped all tests which depend on that test will be skipped too. The advantage of that would be that you can still have other tests in that class which will be executed (because they do not depend on elementVisibleTest).

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach is add group to all such tests let say `flow-1`. Add before group method and throw exception if it doesn't match required condition. For example:

```java
    @BeforeGroups(groups="flow-1")
    public void flow1() {
        if(!requiredCondtionMatch) {
            throw new SkipException("Flow not applicable");
        }
    }
```

If all tests falls under same class then you can use `@BeforeClass` as well.

Comment: Thanks @user861594 It will work for me.. Also can we have something so that error trace does not print ?

Comment: In that case you need to use IMethodInvocation listener and do the needful in beforInvocation method.